# How to bind the width of Xceed Extended Toolkit splitbutton content to the actual width of the splitbutton?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I'm using the splitbutton control from Xceed's extended toolkit for WPF:

```
    <xctk:SplitButton Name="AddConfigurationSplitButton" Content="Add New Configuration">
        <xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Button 1" />
                <Button Content="Button 2"/>
                <Button Content="Button 3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
    </xctk:SplitButton>
```

The problem is that the buttons 1-3 are of different width as the splitbutton. I don't want to give fixed values to either the splitbutton width or the buttons width in its dropdown content. 
As far as I know, binding the width of an element to the actual width of another element goes like this:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AddConfigurationSplittButton}"
```

However, this doesn't work with the splitbutton. 
I also tried to bind it using it's relative parent as follows:

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

This also doesn't work.

Somehow it seems that this control's properties aren't accessible this way. How can I make the width of the dropdown content equal to the splitbutton itself?

Comment: Try to use `Width="{Binding ElementName=AddConfigurationSplittButton, Path=ActualWidth}"`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski isn't that the same as `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AddConfigurationSplittButton}"`? Anyway, I have already tried that too (as I tried out all possible things I could think of) and it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to use `x:Name` instead of `Name` for split button?

Comment: yep, that too, no difference. I also tried to create a new button and bind it's content to the name of the splitbutton, but it also just stays empty, so the properties of the splitbutton don't seem to be available....